# What does the emergency dialer let you do?

Tags: iphone, ios, call

I’m curious, but haven't tested: What does the emergency dialer let you do? If you don’t unlock the phone and press the `Emergency` button, it shows a phone keypad. Can you only dial emergency numbers? What happens if you try calling a normal number?

Comment: You can only dial emergency numbers. They vary by region 911, 112 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only dial emergency numbers, which vary by country/region (**911** in the US; certain countries such as France have multiple emergency numbers). Dialing regular numbers produces the following error:

[image]

Starting with iOS 8, you may also dial emergency contacts by opening your **Medical ID**. Interestingly, as of iOS 9.3.4, if you have one of those numbers memorized, you cannot punch it in directly. You must go through the **Medical ID** to ring it up.

Comment: Note that 112 is the International Emergency number & you should be able to ring it from anywhere.